# Numerical index structure out of a folder structure

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm new to this and I will do my best to ask this question correctly. I need to create a numerical index structure out of a folder/document structure as such.

I have this information:

```
C:\Question\General Information1
C:\Question\General Information1\Articles of Inc
C:\Question\General Information1\Articles of Inc\document .pdf
C:\Question\General Information1\Articles of Inc\document 2.pdf
C:\Question\General Information1\Articles of Inc\document 3.jpg
C:\Question\General Information1\Board Minutes
C:\Question\General Information1\Board Minutes\document .pdf
```

Out of the above I need to create something like this:

```
1.1 C:\Question\General Information1
1.1.1 C:\Question\General Information1\Articles of Inc
1.1.1.1 C:\Question\General Information1\Articles of Inc\document .pdf
1.1.1.2 C:\Question\General Information1\Articles of Inc\document 2.pdf
1.1.1.3 C:\Question\General Information1\Articles of Inc\document 3.jpg
1.1.2 C:\Question\General Information1\Board Minutes
1.1.2.1 C:\Question\General Information1\Board Minutes\document .pdf
```

I have thousands of lines of documents and folders and have a need to create a numerical index.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll assume that your filenames are in Column `A`, starting in row 1. 
If not, make the appropriate adjustments to the below.

Set `B1` to

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "\", ""))
```

and drag/fill it down to cover all your data. 
`SUBSTITUTE(A1, "\", "")` replaces all the `\` characters in your text
with nothing,
so `C:\Question\General Information1` becomes `C:QuestionGeneral Information1`,
which, obviously, has two fewer characters. 
Subtracting the length of this reduced string from the original filename
is a trick for determining the number of `\` characters in your data.

Set `C1` to

```
=IF($B1>=(COLUMN()-2), 1, "")
```

and drag/fill to the right far enough to cover the maximum number of levels
(i.e., number of `\` characters) you expect to have in your data. 
If you don’t know, just drag it to `Z1`; that will allow for 24 levels (26−2). 
If you need more than that,
make the appropriate adjustments to the next section.

`COLUMN()` returns the *number* of the current column
(`C` is 3, `Z` is 26, etc.) 
So `(COLUMN()-2)` ranges from 1 in Column `C` to 24 in Column `Z`. 
This generates the numerical index of the first filename on the list. 
(Remember, `B1` contains the number of directory levels.) 
The formula evaluates to `1` in the columns whose relative column number
(the one in the 1-24 range) is ≤ the number of directory levels,
and blank otherwise. 
So columns 1 and 2 (`C` and `D`) get `1`, and the rest get blank:

```
C       D       E       F   ...
1       1
```

which we will eventually translate into `1.1`.

Set `C2` to

```
=IF($B2>(COLUMN()-2), C1, IF($B2=(COLUMN()-2), SUM(C1,1), ""))
```

and drag/fill to the right far enough to cover the maximum number of levels
(i.e., to match Row 1);
and then drag/fill that down to cover all your data
(i.e., to match Column `B`). 
This is intended to generate the component numbers of your index numbers;
for example, `C2` = `D2` = `E2` = `1`, `F2` … `Z2` are blank,
for an index of `1.1.1`.  It says,

- If the level number is greater than the column number,
  keep the index component from the previous row. 
  For example, since your 6th and 7th values all have at least three backslashes,
  Columns `C`, `D`, and `E` have the same values (`1`, `1`, and `2`)
  in Rows 6 and 7.
- If we’re in the column corresponding to the level number,
  this is where we need to add one to the index component from the previous row. 
  For example, since your 3rd, 4th, and 5th values all have four backslashes,
  cells `F3`, `F4`, and `F5` have the sequential values `1`, `2`, and `3`. 
  (Remember that Column `F` has a relative column number of four,
  since we’re subtracting `2`.)

  - I used `SUM(C1,1)` rather than `C1+1`
    because `SUM(C1,1)` will evaluate to `1` if `C1` is a blank string,
    whereas `C1+1` will result in an error.
- Otherwise, we’re in the column beyond the level number, so display blank.

Now, set `AC1` to

```
=IF(C1="", "", C1&".")
```

This simply says, if cell `C1` has an index component,
append a period (“**`.`**”), otherwise, display blank. 
Drag/fill this to the right far enough to match the Column `C` …, data;
e.g., to `AZ1`.  Set `AB1` to

```
=AC1&AD1&AE1&AF1&AG1&AH1&AI1&AJ1
```

also extending it as far as necessary.  (Yes, this is tedious;
unfortunately, Excel isn’t smart enough for `CONCATENATE(AC1:AZ1)` to work. 
Luckily, you need to do it only once.) 
This concatenates the punctuated index components from Columns `AC` …,
giving you *almost* what you want.  The only problem is that,
since each of the non-blank `AC`-`AZ` values ends with a period,
the concatenation will, also.  So set `AA1` to

```
=LEFT(AB1, LEN(AB1)-1)
```

This is the left-most substring of `AB1` containing all but the last character;
i.e., it removes the final period. 
Drag Columns `AA`-`AZ` down to cover the data.  This should be what you want:

[image]